# android- How to make an existing fragment implement an activity's listener?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, listener

I'm going from a Fragment -> Activity. In the activity I make an interface and when the user clicks a button I pass in a string to an interface object I create and call finish(). In the fragment I implement that interface and want to get that string. But in the activity I get a crash saying the listener is null.

```
public class SampleActivity  extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button button;
    private MatchActivity.OnMatchCompleteListener onMatchCompleteListener;
    public interface OnMatchCompleteListener
    {
        public void matchComplete(String matchID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButton); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onMatchCompleteListener.matchComplete("finished");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements SampleActivity.OnMatchCompleteListener{

    private View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login , container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void matchComplete(String matchID) {
        Log.d("TEST",matchID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have your fragment in the `R.layout.activity_main` and your fragment id is `R.id.fragment` use this:

```
onMatchCompleteListener =
 ((SampleFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment))
```

otherwise use this solution:

```
SampleFragment fragment = new SampleFragment();
onMatchCompleteListener = fragment;
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.layout.activity_main, fragment, "TAG_SIMPLE").commit();
```

Comment: the fragment is not in the activity

Comment: add second solution to activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: i see, ill try that